# Invalid character trying to login terraforms with google cloud. using cygwin

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, terraform, cygwin, mobaxterm

I am trying to use terraform with Mobaxterm (cygwin) on my windows device.   I have successfully authenticated with token using the.

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

however when I try and use terraform with "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" environmental variable set.  I get a strange error:

```
    terraform.exe init
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: storage.NewClient() failed: dialing: google: error getting credentials using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: invalid character '!' looking for beginning of value
```

│
│
╵

the format of my application_default_credentials.json file is:

```
    {
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "quota_project_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "type": "authorized_user"
}
```

I am not sure what the issue is.   There are no "!" in the .json file.

Any ideas?   Has anyone gotten terraform/gcp and cygwin working?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the file **application_default_credentials.json** as the service account specified by **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**.

If you want to use ADC (Application Default Credentials) created by **gcloud auth application-default login**, then delete (clear) the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**. The libraries that Terraform use will then use the credentials saved by the CLI (gcloud).